# File encrypt with php

Tags: php

i need to encrypt a variable before it is passed into a file

code for encryption

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    
    $text_message = "<div class='msgln'><span class='chat-time'>".date("g:i A")."</span> <b class='user-name'>".$_SESSION['name']."</b> ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>";

    $simple_string = $text_message;
    
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";
    
    $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
    $options = 0;
    
    $encryption_iv = '1234567891011121';
    
    $encryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks";
    
    $encryption = openssl_encrypt($simple_string, $ciphering,
                $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);

    file_put_contents("log.html", $encryption, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

i can do that
but when i decrypt the file and pass the data into the needed file it is not decrypting

code to decrypt the file

```
<?php
if(file_exists("log.html") && filesize("log.html") > 0){
    $contents = file_get_contents("log.html");
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

    // Use OpenSSl Encryption method
    $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
    $options = 0;
    $decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';
    
    $decryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks";
    
    $decryption=openssl_decrypt ($contents, $ciphering, 
            $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv);
    
    echo "Decrypted String: " . $decryption;
    echo;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Alwin, do you get any errors?

Comment: no i dont get any eroor

Comment: you can loook it in here  playground.bestyougot.epizy.com

Comment: For every `if`, please always include a final `else` that you can test, even if you think it can never happen. This might be a subset of code and you've done that, but I had to say it. Also, instead of `echo`, prefer `var_dump`, and don't concatenate, dump each individually, otherwise you can hide a lot of information when debugging. I tested your code and it is working correctly. Please perform a boolean test on `openssl_decrypt` and `openssl_encrypt`, both of which can return false. Also, you are appending to that file, that seems weird.